# in Javascript, how can I make input boxes that changes as the values inside them change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know I might not be explaining myself very well but here is the code. I am experimenting with javascript by making a program that calculates square feet.

JS, in head

```
function myFunction()
{
    var x =0;
    var y =0;
    var z =0;

    x =document.getElementById("sqrft");
    y = document.getElementById("length");
    z = document.getElementById("width");
    if(x>0 && y>0)
    {
        x.value=y*z;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<p>A function is triggered when the user releases a key in the input field. The function transforms the character to upper case.</p>
Enter your length: <input type="text" id="length" onkeyup="myFunction()">
Enter your width: <input type="text" id="width" onkeyup="myFunction()">
Enter your totalsqrft: <input type="text" id="sqrft" onkeyup="x.value">
```

So basically I am trying to make the value of "sqrft" change live as the value of length and width changes.

Comment: x.value=y.value *z.value;

Comment: hmmm I see I did that but it still does not display the value of x on the input box.

Comment: might be a bit of an overkill but you might want to check out http://angularjs.org

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var z = 0;

    x = document.getElementById("sqrft"); 
    y = document.getElementById("length").value; // get value of y
    z = document.getElementById("width").value;// get value of z
    if (y > 0 && z > 0) { // compare value of y and z instead of x and y
        x.value = y * z;
    }
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bn886/)**

Comment: I ssee that you mean, that way I can get the actual value of y and z that way. My problem now is displaying the value as y and z change when user gives input. I appreciate your help by the way.

Comment: I don't get what you want. Can you rephrase your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction() {
  var width = +document.getElementById("width").value;
  var height =+document.getElementById("length").value;    
    if (width > 0 && height > 0) { 
        var area = width * height;
  document.getElementById("sqrft").value = area;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/z98gb/82/)

Answer (score 0):

```
x.value=y.value *z.value;
```

You're just getting a reference to the y and z elements. Not their value.

You should probably also do some checks to ensure that you're getting a number back first as well in case users enter text you don't expect

Comment: how can you get the actual value? in this type of function?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like event change.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is `event-delegation`: you use an enclosing div and put a `listener` on the `change` event (simplified HTML):

```
<div id="calc">
    <input name="height" id="height"/><label for="height">height</label>
    <input name="width" id="width"/><label for="height">width</label>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>


document.querySelector("#calc").addEventListener("change", function(){
    document.querySelector("#result").textContent="result: "+document.querySelector("#height").value*1*document.querySelector("#width").value*1
});
```

This is a quite hacky solution, but should show you the way. 
The JSFiddle to play with is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TP7DK/)

Read the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)-article about `querySelector` for explanation and compatibility questions.